# comtypes com object's method returns: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__ctypes_from_outparam__'

Tags: python, com, ctypes, pywin32, comtypes

I'm invoking a method of COM object with string argument using `comtypes` and  method returns (it should return a COM string):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-009507ff0086> in <module>()
----> 1 obj1=xobjData.GetDataType('string_name')

C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.pyc in call_with_inout(self_, *args, **kw)
    657             # be iterable.
    658             if len(outargs) == 1:  # rescode is not iterable
--> 659                 return rescode.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
    660 
    661             rescode = list(rescode)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__ctypes_from_outparam__'
```

Seems very cryptic error, any help?

`%debug` magic shows following:

```
> c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py(659)call_with_inout()
    658             if len(outargs) == 1:  # rescode is not iterable
--> 659                 return rescode.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
    660 

ipdb> outargs
{0: VARIANT(vt=0x8, u'string_name')}
ipdb> rescode
(VARIANT(vt=0x8, u'string_name'), u'Long')
ipdb> print(dir(outargs))
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
ipdb> print(dir(rescode))
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'count', 'index']
ipdb> u
> <ipython-input-112-83ed14b8961f>(1)<module>()
----> 1 xobjData.GetDataType(u'string_name')

ipdb> d
> c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py(659)call_with_inout()
    658             if len(outargs) == 1:  # rescode is not iterable
--> 659                 return rescode.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
    660 

ipdb> exit
```

Comment: https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/issues/87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in comtypes, see fix here:

https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/issues/87

Comment: By native I meant built-in types such as `str` and `int`. Anyway, I think the bug is on line 658. It should check whether `outnum == 1 and len(outargs) == 1` instead of `len(outargs) == 1`. The `outargs` dict only has in/out arguments, not output-only arguments. In the initial loop `outnum` is incremented for both types of output arguments.

Comment: @eryksun, then please show a snippet, which can be reviewed as answer

Comment: I'm not about to pull the source and create a patch. Try the following in place of 658-659: http://pastebin.com/SQN4gqZ0

Comment: @eryksun your solution is better! please add an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the comtype package that results in the attribute error related to tuples. It can be rectified by replacing a small piece of code by undertaking the following steps:

1. In the Python roots folder, go to Lib\site-packages\comtypes\ and open the file `__init__.py`
2. Go to line number 658, you will find the following piece of code"

   ```
       if len(outargs) == 1:  # rescode is not iterable
               return rescode.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
       rescode = list(rescode)
       for outnum, o in list(outargs.items()):
           try:
               rescode[outnum] = o.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
   ```
3. Replace the above piece of code with the following:

   ```
       if len(outargs) == 1:  # rescode is not iterable
           try:
               return rescode.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
           except:
               return rescode
       rescode = list(rescode)
       for outnum, o in list(outargs.items()):
           try:
               rescode[outnum] = o.__ctypes_from_outparam__()
           except:
               rescode[outnum] = o
   ```
4. Save the file `__init__.py` and run your program again.